# Adding a custom property to the VS Project Designer

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am creating a Visual Studio extension and have added a custom configuration-specific property to an existing Microsoft Visual C++ (vcxproj) project using the `IVsBuildPropertyStorage` interface.

I would like to have that custom property show up in the Project Designer's property pages, as part of a new property page. There is some [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-and-removing-property-pages?view=vs-2019) on how to achieve that for a custom project type but the approach relies on reimplementing the project system which is not appropriate for all situations. Is there a way to extend the Project Designer for an existing project type?

Comment: Note that C++ projects do not support subtyping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/project-subtypes?view=vs-2019 - which complicates their extensibility.

Comment: See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1114422/adding-a-custom-property-to-the-vs-project-designe.html?childToView=1120655 for suggestions from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

One way to customise the Project Designer pages for a vcxproj is to include an additional property schema by adding the following:

```
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
<ItemGroup>
<PropertyPageSchema Include="proppage.xml">
  <Context>Project</Context>
</PropertyPageSchema>
</ItemGroup>
```

to a project which can be done by either copying this snippet into the project file directly or by putting it into a custom props file and including that into the project. Details on the structure of a property page schema are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/property-page-xml-files).

The main issue with this approach is that it requires manual intervention or an explicit step for setting up a project to use the custom property page, making it unsuitable for my use case.

It is also bit cumbersome as it requires shipping one-two additional files with the extension and it leaves a footprint in the project file. I would like to come across a more minimalistic solution that automatically applies to all MS VC++ projects but does not modify the project files unless the user inputs a property into the custom property page.