# Creating custom UI property pages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, csproj

In a C# project I have some custom properties added in .csproj like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PropEnabler>True/PropEnabler>
  <PropValue>C:\SomeDir\...\SomeFile.ini</CapabilitiesDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And I would like to create a property page in the .csproj like this:
[image]

I've been searching the internet but I did not find anything relevant for .csproj but some pages relevant for .vcxproj (like [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881782/Creating-custom-UI-property-pages-sheets-in-Visual)) and I've tried to adapt it for .csproj but I failed.

Any suggestions or idea would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: VS2022 overhauled their project-properties pages, so I'm unsure about VS2022, but for VS2002 through VS2019 the only way to customize `*.csproj` project-properties is with a Visual Studio Extension via `EnvDTE`.

Comment: The current documentation for VS2022's new project-properties pages makes no reference to being able to customize them, fwiw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/project-properties-reference?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Dai, I didn't found any useful references for older VS either. Although i found [this](https://hmemcpy.com/2015/03/adding-a-custom-property-page-to-existing-project-types-in-visual-studio/) - but i couldn't make it work.

Comment: Creating custom UI property pages via csproj is not clearly documented in Visual Studio 2022. But I found a solution provided by the OP regarding vcxproj. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912534/adding-a-custom-property-to-the-vs-project-designer